# Display WordPress Search

Tags: functions, search, customization

I am trying to display the current WordPress search term on single.php, index.php, and category.php...basically when someone searches for something I'd like WordPress to remember what the last search term was and display it anywhere on my site, is that possible?

The function `get_search_query` only works on search.php

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: What do you mean by "remember" precisely? For each user? Anonymous visitor? For how long? It's not quite "current" when you are no longer in search context.

Comment: Just until the next search has been performed or after the standard php session time (24 minutes)

Comment: I imagine it would need to be saved in a cookie, it can't be user meta because the visitor may not be logged in. Keep in mind this won't work if the solution is PHP based and you're relying on page caching, it'd have to be javascript based, which probably means local storage. `get_search_query` only works on search.php because search.php is used when searching. If you're not searching it won't work as there is no search query to get. This implies a lack of understanding of how the templating system works and how templates are loaded

Comment: Also WordPress doesn't use PHP Sessions it uses cookie sessions

Comment: See comment on my answer to your related question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155331/wordpress-single-conditional-for-search-page

Comment: @karpstrucking: I wasn't sure how to implement this or the other solution you suggested, so I decided to do something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom,

You're right! I didn't know how templates function, this was not something major, I just wanted to get that value and then display that value on my single.php page - but now I see that's not how WordPress works. I decided to just leave off that functionality :-)

Thanks,
Josh