# WordPress Single Conditional for Search Page

Tags: search, conditional-tags, single

Is there a way to filter single.php so that if someone came from search.php it would display one thing, but if they came from anywhere else it would display another?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Related http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155323/display-wordpress-search#comment223904_155323

Comment: They are only related because they are discussing search.php...in one of them I am trying to figure out how to create a custom single.php file if someone comes from the search page, in the other I am trying to display the search term (what someone searches for) across selected pages in the site.

Comment: If the answer to this question is no, then the other question is no, if the answer to this question is yes, then that answer is about 80%~ of the work needed to do the others. Any comments or answers are extremely relevant to eachother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an `if` statement to solve my problem:

```
<?
    if (stripos(wp_get_referer(), "cat=")!==false) {
        echo "Came from Search";
    } else {
        echo "Didn't come from Search";
    }
?>
```

I am doing a category search, so I check to see if cat= is in the referrer url (or search url), if it is I execute some code, if not I execute some different code :-)

That's it!

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

You could hook into the `the_permalink` filter and check for `is_search()` to conditionally modify the URLs of your search results to include some additional parameters that your `single.php` then checks for. Something like this (may require tinkering):

```
add_filter( 'the_permalink', 'wpse155331_the_permalink' );
function wpse155331_the_permalink( $url ) {
  if ( is_search() ) {
    $url = add_query_arg( array( 'from_search' => 'true' ), $url );
  }
  return $url;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to incorporate the search term from your other related question in the same code - just add the search term as another key/value pair in the `add_query_arg` function.

Comment: karpstrucking, I'm not sure how to integrate this, but I was able to find out how to do this another way. Thanks for the help :-)